# Bar icons disabled on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, navigationbar

So in one of my pages of my app I have a `UIWebView` setup, along with navigation buttons to go back, and forward between history. Well I wanted to enable and disable those buttons when the `UIWebView` couldn't go back or forward, so I used this:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (webView.canGoBack) {
        [_backButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_backButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

    if (webView.canGoForward) {
        [_forwardButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_forwardButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

    return YES;

}
```

This works just fine on the *iPhone* side but not on the *iPad*, on the iPhone when the `UIWebView` cannot go back or forward it disables the icon or button. On the iPad they are always enabled. The buttons are both on a navigation bar, exactly the same, both use the same `viewcontroller.h` and `viewcontroller.m` and the buttons I just matched exactly the same to the same file owners.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Its really starting to get on my nerves and I dont understand why it works on one and not the other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seriously though its like no one knows whats happening. This is my second time posting on here. And i've already posted on reddit twice. No one knows. -_- guess im calling apple dev support tomorrow if no one can help me by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling pretty stupid for this and glad I didn't waste one of my support tickets on this. I forgot inside the iPad story board to apply the UIWebView I was using to a delegate.